# web3.eth.getAccounts(); current not working

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have five accounts set up on Metamask, from Ganache.

I've selected one with 1000 test Ether.

But...

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
const account = accounts[0];
```

`accounts` is always an array of length one.

Why is that?

Also the account in the array is the first account, NOT the currently selected one.

Is there something I am missing this how this works? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Metamask let you connect only one account so your accounts array will always be of length one.
See this topic:
https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/5607

You need to reload the page after changing account in Metamask for it to be considered or handle the change account event as suggested here in the 3rd answer:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/63823

Comment: I do not think you need to reload anymore and the event is already effective.